# Vaadin - multiple error handlers

Tags: vaadin, custom-error-handling

The project I'm working on already has a "custom" error handler but I have a task to make another one which handles only one exception. My question is can the two handlers co-exist and if yes - where do I set mine to be used by the project?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Documentation page about handling errors](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/application/application-errors.html):

> You can customize the default error handling by implementing a custom ErrorHandler and enabling it with setErrorHandler() in any of the components in the component hierarchy, including the UI, or in the VaadinSession object.

That means that what you need to do is most likely doable, and exception will be handled by first error handler it arrives at - unless you want to have two error handlers on the same component (i.e. UI) which is impossible.